# Problem with injection point and non-proxyable dependencies

Tags: java, dependency-injection

Can anyone explain me why if I have my class so defined

```
public abstract class GenericClient
{
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GenericClient.class);

  @Inject
  @ConfigProperty( name = "dirx-ws.url" )
  private String              url;

  private final Client        client;

  private HttpHeaders         httpHeaders;

  public GenericClient()
  {
    this.client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
  }

  public void setHttpHeaders( final HttpHeaders httpHeaders )
  {
    this.httpHeaders = httpHeaders;
  }

  protected HttpHeaders getHttpHeaders()
  {
    return this.httpHeaders;
  }

  protected Client getClient()
  {
    return this.client;
  }

  protected MultivaluedMap<String, Object> getHeaders()
  {
    final MultivaluedMap<String, String> myHttpHeaders = this.httpHeaders.getRequestHeaders();

    final MultivaluedMap<String, Object> result = new MultivaluedHashMap<String, Object>();

    myHttpHeaders.forEach(( name, values ) -> {
      result.putSingle(name, values.size() != 1 ? values : values.get(0));
    });

    printHeaderInfo();

    return result;
  }

  protected UriBuilder createURIBuilder( final String... paths )
  {
    final UriBuilder uriBuilder = UriBuilder.fromUri(this.url);
    
    for (final String path : paths)
    {
      uriBuilder.path(path);
    }
    
    return uriBuilder;
  }
}
```

there is no error, while if I define it this way (the only changes are *private UriBuilder createdURI;* and and the updated method *createURIBuilder*)

```
public abstract class GenericClient
{
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GenericClient.class);

  @Inject
  @ConfigProperty( name = "dirx-ws.url" )
  private String              url;

  private final Client        client;

  private HttpHeaders         httpHeaders;

  private UriBuilder          createdURI;

  public GenericClient()
  {
    this.client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
  }

  public void setHttpHeaders( final HttpHeaders httpHeaders )
  {
    this.httpHeaders = httpHeaders;
  }

  protected HttpHeaders getHttpHeaders()
  {
    return this.httpHeaders;
  }

  protected Client getClient()
  {
    return this.client;
  }

  protected MultivaluedMap<String, Object> getHeaders()
  {
    final MultivaluedMap<String, String> myHttpHeaders = this.httpHeaders.getRequestHeaders();

    final MultivaluedMap<String, Object> result = new MultivaluedHashMap<String, Object>();

    myHttpHeaders.forEach(( name, values ) -> {
      result.putSingle(name, values.size() != 1 ? values : values.get(0));
    });

    printHeaderInfo();

    return result;
  }

  protected final UriBuilder createURIBuilder( final String... paths )
  {
    if (this.createdURI == null)
    {
      this.createdURI = UriBuilder.fromUri(this.url);

      for (final String path : paths)
      {
        this.createdURI.path(path);
      }
    }

    return this.createdURI;
  }
}
```

I get the error

> WELD-001410: The injection point has non-proxyable dependencies:
> [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private
> ch.ethz.id.sws.iamws.webservices.endpoint.RequestInterceptor.userClient
> [INFO]  at
> ch.ethz.id.sws.iamws.webservices.endpoint.RequestInterceptor.userClient(RequestInterceptor.java:0)

My RequestScoped **UserClient** class has (only) an empty public constructor and it extends GenericClient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Removing **final** from createURIBuilder method did the job.

I would be glad if someone could explain me anyway the reason why setting the method as 'final' is a problem.